# How to fetch Android preferences XML file using PHP?

Tags: php, android, xml

I tried to fetch data from an XML file. This file is an Android preferences XML file, so the XML map and build are so different.

I can access the file, but I don’t get the expected result.

Example of my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="prefSipIntercom7Id"></string>
    <string name="pref_WeatherLast_Icon">01d</string>
    <string name="project_code">******</string>
    <string name="serial_number">*****</string>
</map>
```

This is my code:

```php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$data = $xmlDoc->load("com.smartcozum.spad_preferences.xml");
$obj3 = $xmlDoc->saveXML($xmlDoc);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($obj3);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$counter = count($array['string']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) { 
    if(is_array($array['string'][$i])){
        print_r($array['string'][$i]['@attributes']);
    } else {
        echo $array['string'][$i];
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [name] => prefSipIntercom7Id )
```

Here the value `01d` is missing.

**Expected result:**

```
Array ( [name] => prefSipIntercom7Id, [value] => 01d )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not accessing it with the DomDocument instance, as you already have initialized it. Just create an array with the needed informations.

```
$doc = new \DomDocument();
$doc->load($filename);

$data = [];
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('string');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
     $data[$element->getAttribute('name')] = $element->nodeValue;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

The expected result is ...

```
[
    'prefSipIntercom7Id' => '',
    'pref_WeatherLast_Icon' => '01d',
    'project_code' => '***',
    'serial_number' => '***',
]
```